# Can you edit a JSFiddle without changing its URL

Tags: jsfiddle

I have some code at JSFiddle. The URL is something like:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/<username>/<uniquecode>/4/
```

I have shared the URL, but afterwords, I found some "typo's" that I need to correct.

My understanding is that if I edit the JSFiddle, I have to save it (update) for the changes I made to be saved, but If I use "update", the JSFiddle will be given a new URL like:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/<username>/<uniquecode>/5/
```

Can I edit a JSFiddle without changing its URL?

Is there a better way to do this so that I can share a JSFiddle and still be able to edit what people see at the URL I shared?

Answer (score 4):

You have to Update the fiddle, then click <kbd>Set as Base</kbd> in the top menu bar.  You need to create or fork the fiddle yourself before you see the Base button.  If you are using a Fiddle that *you* did not personally create *while logged in*, then pressing <kbd>Set as Base</kbd> is going to create a new Fiddle at a new URL.

**Note:** The <kbd>Set as Base</kbd> button is only available to registered, logged-in users (as of February 2017, at least). The button is located between `Fork` and `Tidy` in the top menu bar.

Comment: When I click "Base", will the URL change with a new number at the end? Right now, the URL ends in "/4/". After I click "Base", will the URL change to end in "/5/"?

Comment: If you are currently editing /base/4/, it will update /base/ to point to revision 4 and it will switch back to /base/ in the address bar to reflect that. When you save again, it will be under /base/5/ (until you choose to make 5 the new base).